# Python 2.7's argparse - open file for reading in utf-16

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I'm using module argparse, and I want to have a command line argument of input_file, which is a path to a file in utf-16. I want to use argparse.FileType for something like that:

```
parser.add_argument('input_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

Unfortunately, argparse.FileType `__init__` does not receive encoding parameter.

Is there another way to do so rather than just set the `input_file`'s type to str, and implement a subclass of `argparse.Action` that opens the file with `codecs`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse.FileType` [isn't so long or complicated](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/argparse.py#l1100). You could make your own version that takes an encoding parameter, either by subclassing or just by copying [the source](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/argparse.py#l1100) and modifying it. (Subclassing seems somewhat silly, since you'd have to override the entire class except maybe `__repr__`.)